# ClassCastException when setting an OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have an `arrayAdapter` for a `ListView`. Inside this `arrayAdapter` I am calling a method which is for some reason causing a `ClassCastException`.

**The arrayAdapter**

```
String[] strings = /*...*/;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.item,strings);
ListView listView = (ListView) (findViewById(R.id.listView));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Crashing code**

```
private void addListener() {
    ListView listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Is "R.id.s5_tv_friend_request_list" in your layout.xml is LisView?

Comment: "_how can I fix that_" Don't try to cast a class into something it isn't.

Comment: TextView friend_request = (TextView) viewClicked;   contains error.
If you are using ArrayAdapter then use TextView friend_request = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

Comment: can you post the code where you are adding adapter to list

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin post the adapter code pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view being clicked in your ListView isn't a TextView. The TextView is likely contained in the layout of the ListItem itself. So it woud be something like

```
 TextView friendRequest = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.friend_request);
```

Notice the standard variable naming convention, it is good practice to declare variables in modified camel case and xml in the fashion you named your variable (with underscore space modifiers).

If that isn't the case, check to make sure you are actually using the correct list -

The line `ListView s5_lv_friend_request_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.s5_tv_friend_request_list);` makes the implication that

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/s5_tv_friend_request_list"
     ... />
```

Is contained somewhere in your xml for your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work, if each row from the Adapter is inflating TextView (convertView == TextView)..if that is true, it's OK. If not, you have to do a:

```
TextView text = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(THE_ID_OF_THE_TEXT_VIEW);
```